# Настройка сообщения об ошибке. Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel

Есть в таблице `images` поле с уникальным значением

```
$table->string('url')->unique();
```

при записи существующего `url`, генерируется ошибка:  `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry`
Я перехватываю ошибку с помощью `try catch` и вывожу текст ошибки.
Подскажите, как можно выводить своё сообщение об ошибке вместо текущего сообщения?
К примеру если по `ajax` сохранять изображение, после сохранения выводится данное сообщение `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry`, и нужно его настроить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри catch проверить, что это именно такая ошибка, и вернуть свой текст.
В противном случае снова выбросить ошибку чтобы она была обработана глобальным обработчиком ошибок

```
if ($message === "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry") {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Уже есть такая фамилия, насяльник!']);
} else {
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Код ошибки нужно проверять, а не сообщение

Comment: Это верно. сообщения могут быть, прости господи, локализованными